# Can I use a different linux distribution in an LXC container?

Tags: lxc

We are developing a server product targeted for Debian Lenny (and some others). However, due to driver needs, developers' personal choices etc. we run Ubuntu (12.04) on the hardware.

Is it possible to run Debian Lenny in an LXC container on Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to run a different distribution, but the kernel that's being used, has to be the same.

So if your Debian and ubuntu use the same kernel or can work with the same kernel, there shouldn't be a problem. I don't know however if 12.04 can support the latest lenny kernel (it's pretty dated and support has been dropped for lenny by debian).